# Implementing GUI pop-ups on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any way to implement pop-ups similar to the system ones on iPhone? I'd like to see something similar to pop-ups used with Copy/Paste in 3.0 [(screenshots)](http://dailykermit.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/iphone-3-0-copy-and-paste-walkthrough-and-landscape-keyboard/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of, is to write it yourself.
I think this type of popup is too new to have some open-source implementation available.